# Good approach of a maven project design or antipattern design

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

**Context:**

I have a multimodules maven project that looks like:

Root ---- ModuleA

```
      ModuleB
      ModuleC
      ModuleD
      .......
```

They are around 25 modules under the Root:

- A few of them represent the core of the application  (5 modules)
- And each of the remaining modules represent the business processes implementation related to a type a customers. These modules are completely independant among each others.

When packaging or releasing the 'Root' project, the artifact generated is a single ZIP file aggregating all the JARs related to 'Root' modules.

The single ZIP file is generated according to an assembly descriptor, it represents the delivery artifact.

At deployment time on the target environment, the single ZIP is unziped under a directory where it is consumed (class loaded) by an 'engine', a java web application that provides the final services.

**Constraints**

- The 'business constraints' from one side,
- And the willing to reduce regressions between different versions on
  the other side

The above constraints lead us to adopt the following release scenarios:

- Either we release the Root and **ALL** its submodules. It means that
  the resulting ZIP will aggegate all the submodules JAR with the same
  version.  The ZIP will contain something similar to:
  [ModuleA-1.1.jar, ModuleB-1.1.jar, ModuleC-1.1.jar, ModuleD-1.1.jar,
  ......., ModuleX-1.1.jar].
- Or we release the Root and **A FEW** of its submodules, the ones that we want to re update. 
  The resulting ZIP will aggegate all the submodules JAR : The released submodules will be aggregated with the last released versions, the unreleased submodules will be aggregated with another 'appropriate' version. 
  For example, if we made a such incremental release, the ZIP will contain something similar to [ModuleA-1.2.jar, ModuleB-1.1.jar, ModuleC-1.2.jar, ModuleD-1.1.1.jar,
  ......., ModuleX-1.1.2.jar].

These 2 scenarios were made possible by:

- Either declaring the modules as **MAVEN MODULES 'module'** for the first
  scenario
- Or declaring the modules as **MAVEN DEPENDENCIES 'dependency'** for
  the second scenario, the INCREMENTAL scenario.

**Question**

Both scenarios are working perfectly **BUT** when we are in the 2nd scenario (INCREMENTAL), the maven-release-plugin:prepare is uploading to the SCM (svn) all the modules [ModuleA, ModuleB, ModuleD, ....  ModuleX], it is uploading the released and the non released ones, whereas the 'non released modules' are declared as 'dependency' in the pom and not as a 'module'.

1/ IS THERE a way to avoid uploading the 'non released' modules ? Is there a way to inject an 'exlcude directrory list' to SCM svn provider ?

2/ A MORE global question, does the approach used is a correct one ? Or is it an anti pattern usage ? In that case, what should be the alternative ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To me, your approach looks like an antipattern. I recommend to only have projects in the same hierarchy that you want to release together. Projects with a different release lifecycle should live on their own - otherwise you will keep running into the issues you mentioned. If you run the release plugin from a root directory (multi-module setup), all of the content of that root directory will be tagged in SVN.

In your case, I would probably create the following hierarchies:

- Core
- One per customer type
- Potentially one per type to bundle them (zip), depending on your structure

I would group it by the way you create the release. It might mean that you have to run the release plugin a couple of times instead of just once when you make a change e.g. in Core, but it will be a lot cleaner.

Your packaging project will then pull in all of the dependencies and package/assemble them.

If you have common configuration options, I recommend to put them into a common `parent` pom. This doesn't have to be your root (multi-module) pom.

Comment: Hi, the suggested design is cleaner but it will bring more work to the delivery team. I'ld say, it would be great if it is possible to declare Maven Module without the obligation that the 'module' should be a physical diectory inside the Root project directory. I'm thiking if there is a kind of smlink plugin that allows to define the 'modules' at the level of the Root project, and then by releasing the Root project, all its 'sub modules' will be also released, and only these submodules will be uploaded to the SCM. What do you think about that ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run the maven-release-plugin with `-r` argument + the list of all modules you want to release?

Basically, this argument allows you to specify the list of modules against which the maven command should be performed. (if you omit it: all submodules will be included, this the default behavior)

See more details about this command line [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html).

I never try to use it with the maven-release-plugin, and I don't know if it will work, especially regarding SCM operations.